# JQuery Ajax - Resetting Response

Tags: jquery, ajax

Using JQuery Ajax, On radio selection and button click, an ajax request is made and I get a the correct response, However, the response also returns with the previous response as well.

For example, If a user selected an "apple" and clicks submit, the response returns "apple". Next, if that user selects "kiwi," the response returns "apple" and "kiwi." I would only like the response to return the current selection, in this case, the "kiwi."

Here is the code:

```
function get_fruit() {
var selection = $("input[name=fuit]:checked").val();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "../user_selects/",
            data: {selection:selection},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $("body").append(data);
            }
        });

}
```

and the button:

```
<button onclick="get_fruit();">Submit</button>
```

I also have a listing of radio buttons with a fruit. For example, radio button grape, next line, radio button pear,...etc

Comment: What is `fruits` -- post the whole `change` function please :)

Comment: var radio isn't being used?

Comment: data: {selction:fruit} is the var value pair that is sent to the db

Comment: jabrnett, i re-edited, suppose to be selection not radio

Comment: You are using "append" function so you are just adding the current response to the body wothout clearing old one. `Use $("body").html(data);` instead.

Comment: @L105 is correct. You ajax call is only returning the selected value but youre adding it after all of the previous ones. So it appears that both values are being returned.

Comment: Hey thanks L105, the html did the trick. I also like to thank everyone else that responded.